# local variable 'result" referenced before assignment

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I'm trying to import my calculator created using spyder on pandas Jupyter but received the above error. Tried using else: but still getting the error.

Heres my spyder code.

```
import pandas as pd

def calc_convert(Unit,result):

    if Unit == 'mg/g':
        testr = result*0.100
    elif Unit == 'g/day':
        testr = result*100
    elif Unit == 'g/g':
        testr = result*0.100*1000
    else:
        testr = result*1

    return testr
```

here's my pandas jupyter code

```
lst_test = []
for index, row in test.iterrows():
     lst_test.append(calc_convert(row['Unit'],row['result']))

test['converted'] = pd.Series(lst_test,index=test.index)

display(test)
```

This is the traceback error from Jupyter pandas

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-170-5dfe9296da1e> in <module>

      1 lst_test = []

      2 for index, row in test.iterrows():

----> 3     lst_test.append(calc_convert(row['Unit'], row['result']))

      4

      5 test['converted'] = pd.Series(lst_test, index=test.index)

 

     17   elif Unit == 'g/g':

     18       testr = result*0.100*1000

---> 19   else:

     20       testr = result*1

     21

 

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'testr' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Is your indentation of the calc_convert function the same as displayed here?

Comment: Probably nope as I manually typed the code in but there is no indentation errors displayed on spyder when running it.

Comment: Please include the full traceback error and ensure your code is indented properly.

Comment: Included the full traceback error with edits (excluded file directory)

Comment: Your code is correct if you edit indentation. So you are doing something wrong out of code. Reset your kernel. maybe helps.

Comment: Your code is fine.  It clearly in something you're not showing us.

Comment: Agreed with @keramat you should try restarting the kernel

Comment: I've included all the codes and traceback error with the exception of the file directory. I'll try restarting the kernel and update.

Comment: Just an update. Restarting the Kernel worked and I was able to calculate out. Thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the Kernel worked. Thank you everyone for your inputs.